# Distributing R processing on a Hadoop server

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I currently have a R code that runs locally. It consists of a foreach section that I've parallelised successful using the %dopar% function. I hope to convert this loop from a parallelisation on a single CPU to a distribution on Hadoop server.

Can anybody advise me on a suitable approach and which packages I should use?

Additional info: My Hadoop setup is a Hortonworks HDP and my foreach loop is embarrassingly parallel. I hope to make the jump from local parallelisation to cluster distribution for speed improvement. Only the computing/processing needs to be done on the cluster (my data is local - not on the cluster).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a foreach backend that is designed to use Hadoop. You can use `doSNOW`, `doParallel`, and `doMPI` to execute foreach on multiple nodes of a cluster, but they require either ssh or MPI/mpirun to start the workers on the remote nodes. I'm not sure how well that would play with Hadoop.

There are a number of R packages that work with Hadoop (`RHIPE`, `RHadoop`), but I don't know how much work would be required to convert your R code to use them.